# Is it possible to use arithmetic operators in xpath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am taking an xpath from a table and below is a example one.

```
//*[@class='example']//table//tr[1]//td[2].
```

In one of my scenarios I want to add the `tr` value with +1 which will count the `tr` as `tr[2]` in run time. So is there any way to achieve this? I've tried this:

```
//*[@class='example']//table//tr[1+1]//td[2]
//*[@class='example']//table//tr[(1+1)]//td[2]
```

Comment: I tried this //[@class='example']//table//tr[1+1]//td[2]. 
 and //[@class='example']//table//tr[(1+1)]//td[2] but none works

Comment: You are missing tag or `*` after `//` -> `//*[@class='example']`

Comment: Nope, the xpath is for reference purpose. My question is, whether we can have the arithmetic operations within the array of tr tag

Comment: I don't see any issue with `//*[@class='example']//table//tr[1+1]//td[2]` and `//*[@class='example']//table//tr[(1+1)]//td[2]`. You should be good with that approach, but make sure to type cast the row index to int and then add +1 then cast to string `str(index+1)`.

Comment: Btw which language you are using.

Comment: I am working on selenium using java.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :

**Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class TestExp {
    String xpathStr ="//*[@class='example']//table//tr[%1s]//td[2]";
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestExp testExp = new TestExp();
        testExp.clickBtn("1");
        testExp.clickBtn("2");
    }
    public void clickBtn(String index){
        try {
            String element = String.format(xpathStr,index);
            System.out.println(element);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        }catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
            System.out.println("Element is not found");
        }
    }
}
```

**Result :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be normally possible just remember to use [`div` for division](https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_number_operators.cfm) as `/` is reserved character which selects the [root node](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Demo:

[image]

See [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) for more XPath tips and tricks

It's much easier to work with HTML [tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) using [Table](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) class of the [HtmlElements framework](http://htmlelements.qatools.ru)